# How to Install ITL extension

Tags: php, php-extension

I want to install the [PHP ITL extension](http://svn.arabeyes.org/viewvc/projects/itl/ports/php/) so I can use it.

Do I need to compile this, and if so, how do I compile it? I need it to work for both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not read the [**README**](http://svn.arabeyes.org/viewvc/projects/itl/ports/php/README?revision=11087&view=markup)?

> - libitl must be already be installed along with header files.
> - Download php source code and create directory $PHP_SRC_DIR/ext/itl
>     and copy the files config.m4 itl.c php_itl.h and itl.php to it
> - Run the following commands
>         cd $PHP_SRC_DIR/ext/itl
>         phpize
>         ./configure --with-itl=/path/to/libitl
> - The ITL functions can be enabled by compiling the php-itl extension and copying the resulting .so file to PHP's extension directory.

Comment: Hehe, I used to think that way. Fortuntately not anymore :)

Comment: lol i have read the readme, but i dont want to compile it with php, i just want to add it on php.ini and run it like i do with other extension.. phppdf.ext you know..

Comment: The steps described in the readme show how to compile the extension in Linux. The result is a .so file you can include in your PHP.ini. As for Windows, that's a different matter - I don't know how to produce it there. Maybe asking the project maintainers for ready-made Windows binaries helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the README: http://svn.arabeyes.org/viewvc/projects/itl/ports/php/README?revision=11087&view=markup

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at [this section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php) in the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/). Specifically [this section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php) on compiling extensions with the `phpize` command.